# Connection between PostgreSQL and Symfony3 (Doctrine)

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm starting a symfony project and i got a PosgreSQL database. I work on Windows 10 and Xampp

I know that xampp works with postgreSQL (i edited php.ini to make it work) because the postgre driver is shown in phpinfo and i did a php script test to connect to the DB and it works.

This is what i get in config.yml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: pdo_pgsql
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: 5432
    database_name: postgres
    database_user: postgres
    database_password: toto
    charset: UTF8
```

However, whenever i try to use a basic console command with symfony like

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

it returns :

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
An exception occured in driver: could not find driver

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
could not find driver

[PDOException]
could not find driver
```

EDIT : after some hours of searching it, i figured that i had a different php folder that my console used. I've uninstalled it and added the php runned by xampp in my environment variables. And then the console used the right php and the doctrine command worked.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

execute `php -m` in your CMD if you don't see `pdo_pgsql` so you need to add the extension to php.ini that php execute

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've run this command and pdo_pgsql is shown in the module list

Answer (score 0):

If you're using php7.0:
**sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql**

For ondrej/php Ubuntu repository with php7.1:
**sudo apt-get install php7.1-pgsql**

Same repository, but for php5.6:
**sudo apt-get install php5.6-pgsql**